# Exporting table with colspan and formatting in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, export-to-pdf, html-to-pdf

I have created a page in angular js which uses the ng-repeat tag to populate the data in a table. I have used some formatting and colspan. I am trying to export the table in pdf. I have tried the below approaches:

1. htmltoCanvas: used the below code:

   ```
   $scope.export = function(){
     html2canvas(document.getElementById('exportthis'), {
       onrendered: function (canvas) {
         var data = canvas.toDataURL();
         var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape','pt','letter');      
         pdf.addImage(data, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
         pdf.save("download.pdf");
       }
      });
    }
   ```

The issue which i am facing is: since it converts the table to an image, I cannot copy the contents and also if the table is too huge(more than a page) it gives a blank pdf.

2. I used jspdf which does not support colspan and also the formatting is lost.

Please advise.

Comment: for some reason am not able to code, apologies for that...

Comment: Not aware of a good client side solution for this.  wkhtmltopdf works server side using webkit to render a pdf you can also do this pretty simply with phantomjs itself but client side the only PDF generators I've seen require a particular data model for generating the pages.  You might be able to scale things to fit using the method you're trying now but would probably be better to get something that can render it more directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around to solve my issue. Posting it as an answer as it might help someone with the same issue. I am now using a print option and hence I am able to save the div with the formatting.